# How to add tags to android stack traces?

Tags: android, logcat

When using `e.printStackTrace()`, clicking a line in logcat jumps to the offending line of code.

I'd like to add a tag to these traces, but `Log.e(String tag, String msg, Throwable tr)` only prints out the exception name.

Is there a way to do this, that retains the click behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Log.e(TAG, "some descritpion", e);`

This code should produce logs like e.printStackTrace() does but with TAG and that 'click behaviour' is working.

I'm using eclipse with adt 10.0.1, maybe plugin update will help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me with 10.0.0, and the changelog makes no mention of the feature being added. Can anyone confirm otherwise?